# What is the default camel-ftp readLock value for Camel 2.9.x?

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

The Camel documentation mentions that **readLock's** default value is **markerFile**, but this option is not available for ftp. So what is the default value for readLock for the ftp component? Is it **changed**?

Answer (score 1):

There is no default readLock for FTP. If you want to use that you must specify one.

The documentation also states that at: http://camel.apache.org/ftp2

> The option readLock can be used to force Camel not to consume files
>   that is currently in the progress of being written. However, this
>   option is turned off by default, as it requires that the user has
>   write access.